# Visual Studio Code: after typing 'log' to complete 'console.log()', it adds a new empty 'log' suggestion

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Steps to recreate:

**1)** Type `log` and press enter when the suggestion widget appears. VSCode completes it so it types `console.log()`.

Here's an image of what the suggestion widget looks like:

[image: Here's an image of what the suggestion widget looks like]]

**2)** New line in same file: type `log` again, this time it adds a new suggestion to the suggestion dialog. Here's what it looks like (the top one with 'abc' next to it):

[image: Image]]

Pressing enter when this is selected doesn't do anything, just hides the dialog. This means I have to press down arrow and then enter.

---

So it seems it wants to suggest recently typed keywords. This is useful if I want to type a long variable I typed previously, not very useful in this case.

How do I disable the 'abc' log suggestion, **without completely disabling suggestions for recently typed variables?**

I already disabled all my extensions, no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"` to settings.json.

It moved the `console.log` suggestion to the top, fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the settings : "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false

Reload VS Code and try.

Comment: The problem still persists, even after restarting VSCode. Only now when writing HTML it won't suggest class suggestions which is really annoying. Is it possible that setting doesn't work with javascript?

Comment: I just checked the documentation on the official website for VS Code at https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/intellisense/

I think you'll find the correct setting in the documentation.